# Вывод данных из базы и их удаление sql

Tags: python, sql, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня при каждом сообщении от нового пользователя для бота, создается столбец с названный его id.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def info(message):
    cur.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notes (
    '{message.chat.id}' TEXT
)""")
    db.commit()
```

При добавлении новых данных они правильно записываются в нужный столбец, но когда я вызываю вывод данных, то бот отсылает мне не верные значения, а если быть точнее, мой id. Также не удаляются данные.
[image: Скрин базы данных и диалога с ботом]

Код добавления данных:

```
def new_note(message):
        cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO notes ('{message.chat.id}') VALUES (?)", (message.text,))
        db.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Note added successfully')
```

Код вывода данных:

```
elif message.text == ' My notes':
        try:
            msg = ''
            for value in cur.execute(f"SELECT '{message.chat.id}' FROM notes"):
                if msg == '':
                    msg += '• ' + value[0]
                    continue
                msg += '\n• ' + value[0]
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg)
        except Exception:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'No notes found')
```

Код удаления данных:

```
def del_note(message):
    try:
        cur.execute(f"SELECT '{message.chat.id}' FROM notes")
        cntx = cur.fetchall()[int(message.text) - 1]
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Note "{cntx[0]}" deleted')
        cur.execute(f"DELETE FROM notes WHERE '{message.chat.id} = (?)", (cntx))
        db.commit
    except Exception:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Notes number {message.text} not found')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если создавать таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE notes ( id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, chatid TEXT )
```

id нужен, чтобы можно было достать данные, если вписывать, то:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (chatid) VALUES (message.chat.id)
```

доставать:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `chatid` = 'message.chat.id'
```

удолять:

```
DELETE FROM notes WHERE `chatid` = 'message.chat.id'
```